# Does a flexible array member increase sizeof a struct?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, flexible-array-member

I have the following kind of code:

```
typedef struct
{    
    u32 count;
    u16 list[];   
} message_t;
...

message_t* msg = (message_t*)buffer;  
msg->count = 2;
msg->list[0] = 123;
msg->list[1] = 456;

size_t total_size = sizeof(*msg) + sizeof(msg->list[0]) * msg->count;  

send_msg( msg, total_size );
```

Problematic line is the line with sizeofs. I am not sure is that correct way to count needed space.
Does `sizeof(*msg)` contains already something about the `list` member?

I can test it with my compiler, but does every compiler work similary in this case?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: yes, you are right. Your comment is correct answer to the title question. +1 for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's what the standard says:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
>   named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
>   flexible array member. In most situations, the flexible array member
>   is ignored. In particular, **the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted** except that it may have more
>   trailing padding than the omission would imply.

Comment: but, help us interpreting it: does it means sizeof struct + sizeof list * number of element will give the correct size of the "object", the way the OP computes it, or this way one could miss "strange" padding?

Comment: Thanks. The citation to the standard answers to my questions. I'll accept this answer.

About the padding: Cause "*except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply*"
propably mean that sizeof(struct) can be different without the flexible array member. But but in my case it is not a problem.

Comment: @User1: Suppose one has a struct with five `char` fields and an `int[]`, on a platform where `int` required four-byte alignment.  Without the flexible member, the size of the struct would be five bytes with no alignment required; with it, the struct would be eight bytes that must be aligned on a four-byte boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Your example do work since C has not arrays that dynamically become bigger when you add elements. So size of *msg is sizeof u32 + paddings, if any, but it won't count for list member, which you have to consider by yourself when you "alloc" the buffer and when you want to know the actual size of that "object", as you did.