# sizeof of string literal inside a struct - C

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
struct stest
{
    int x;
    unsigned char data[];
} x = 
{
    1, {"\x10\x20\x30\x00\x10"} 
};

int main()
{
    printf( "x.data: %d\n", (int)x.data[0] );
    return 0;
}
```

Which works fine. However, I need to use the size of the "data".

If I do:

```
printf( "sizeof x.data: %d\n", (int)sizeof(x.data) );
```

I get the error:

invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘char[]’

Is there a way to get the size of "data" in this situation, or maybe a suggestion of an alternative method I could use?

The compiler I am using is gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I might have an null byte in my array. I will edit my question expliciting that

Comment: @chux You are right, to get size in byte I need to add 1

Comment: There is a more realistic scenario of what I have in practice

Comment: So the sub-field `x` is now 6 `char` long with an embedded null character and a terminating one.

Comment: but in this case the strlen would not get the real size

Comment: True, `strlen()` will get the length of the string, not counting the first null character and not the field size.  I suspect you are SOL.

Comment: As a note, that whole construct is non-standard C; suggest tagging gcc (or GNU-C or whatever the tag is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since x.data is a null terminated char array you could just use strlen function.

```
printf( "sizeof x.data: %u\n", strlen(x.data)+1 );
```

This code will not work correctly if the array contains null. In this case you need to store length of the array in separate member of struct.

Comment: Consider `%zu` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Ok. Size in byte - strlen()+1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I might have null characters in that array. I have edited the question making that explicit. +1 for updating the answer

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, strlen will get you what you want.

The reason you're running into trouble isn't due to the string literal aspect, but rather [the lack of a definite size of the array in your struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#sizeof_and_incomplete_types). It's an incomplete type.  The compiler doesn't know how big the array is, and so sizeof can't figure it out.

Specifically, this is a "flexible array member". C99 added these. Structs with array's with an incomplete array as the last element (so it has room to grow).

Sizeof gets the size of the datatype. 
Sizeof when applied to arrays, gets the size of the whole array.
Sizeof when applied to structs with a flexible array member, [ignores the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732184/does-a-flexible-array-member-increase-sizeof-a-struct). 
Sizeof when applied to incomplete types simply fails. It gives up trying to figure out how big the array is.

So long story short, slap a number in your array. (Or pass along that information)

```
struct
{
  int x;
  int thesizeofmyarrayisfive = 5;
  unsigned char data[5];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a size field to the structure.

```
#define DATA ("\x10\x20\x30\x00\x10")
struct stest
{
    int x;
    size_t size;
    unsigned char data[];
} x = 
{
    1, sizeof DATA, { DATA } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's only two options:

1. Store a terminating byte. Often people use the null character for this. Of course, you must make sure that the terminating byte is not found in the valid data part of the array.
2. Add a length member to your struct.