# Why does sizeof applied to a structure with a flexible array member not produce the allocated space?

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management, malloc, nodes

I am trying to create a flexible struct in C so that when I allocate memory for it, I do not waste space like I would by declaring my data type to be a constant in size. However, my program does not correctly allocate space. The `printf` statement shows `sizeof` produces eight even though I allocated more space. Why?

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char word[];
} node;

...

    while (fscanf(input, "%s", word) == 1) {
        struct node *w = malloc(sizeof(*w) + 1 + sizeof(strlen(word));
        if (w == NULL) {
            printf("Memory Error\n");
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(w->word, word);
        printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*w));
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a few more details? E.g., what are you seeing that tells you that space is not correctly allocated? Also, as a tip, `sizeof(char [strlen(word)])` could be simplified to `strlen(word)`. And don't forget that you'll probably need space for the null terminator!

Comment: You can only declare 1 of each struct with a FAM (meaning you cannot have an array of struct containing a FAM) Your use in the `while()` loop is fine (though you need to `free()` at the end of the loop to not leak memory), but be aware of the limitation. [C11 Standard - 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3)

Comment: @paddy:  The C standard allows taking the size of a variable length array type, although support for variable length arrays is optional (an implementation choice). The `sizeof` may be evaluated during program execution. It is not a syntax error.

Comment: RE “However, my program does not correctly allocate space”: This is not a good description of a problem. Allocating space is not something that a person can see, so we do not know what you mean. You can see a program’s output or see some of its behavior in a debugger, such as seeing some contents of memory or control paths that are taken. Edit the question to contain a [mre], including a description of the output or behavior you observe and a description of the output or behavior your desire instead.

Comment: That said, change `malloc(sizeof(*w) + sizeof(char [strlen (word)]) )` to `malloc(sizeof *w + sizeof(char [strlen(word)+1]))` to allow for the null character required to terminate a string. (You can also use `malloc(sizeof *w + strlen(word) + 1)`, but including `char` is reasonable to make it easy to change to a wide-character type later.)

Comment: OT: Don't compare the result of `fscanf()` with EOF. The result is the number of fields succesfully scanned.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, I was a bit hasty. `EOF` is returned only if end-of-file or error occurs before any read, else it is >= 0. (And OP should use `fscanf(…) == 1`.)

Comment: @thebusybee: Oops, yes, `==`.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde I just some more info. thanks!

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just added a bit about my output--when I print sizeof(*w) I always get 8.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732231/616815), the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted (aside from padding concerns). So when calculating `sizeof(*w)`, only the `struct node * next` field contributes to the size. Since you're (presumably) on a 64-bit platform, that works out to 8 bytes, as you observe.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` does not determine the size of the object that is its operand. It only determines the size of the type of its operand.

For example, if you allocate an array of 1000 `int` with `int *x = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));`, then `sizeof *x` returns the size of one `int`, because the type of `*x` is `int`.

For `sizeof *w`, where `w` is a structure with a flexible array member, `sizeof` returns the size of the type, which is the base size of the structure. It does not know how much extra space you allocated for the structure.

The base size of the structure is the same as the size as if the structure had been defined without the flexible array member, except it may have more padding (which may be needed if the flexible array element type requires more alignment than other things in the structure).

So, after `struct node *w = malloc(sizeof(*w) + 1 + sizeof(strlen (word));`, `sizeof *w` will give you only `sizeof (struct node)`, not the allocated size.

Comment: Thank you!! So you're saying I actually did everything correctly, but my printf statement wasn't showing the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Eric, `sizeof` evaluates to the size of the type of its operand. This evaluation is performed at compile time, except for border cases such as `sizeof(char[fun()])` and variable length arrays. Even in these cases, the size is not associated with the object itself, and only available in the scope where the object is defined. The flexible array at the end of `node` is not included in the size of `node` objects and the allocated size depends on each and every instance.

Incidentally, the posted code does not allocate the correct size (it does not actually compile): `malloc(sizeof(*w) + 1 + sizeof(strlen(word));` should be:

```
malloc(sizeof(*w) + 1 + strlen(word));
```

Many C libraries provide an extension to retrieve the size of a block allocated from the heap by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` etc. Here are some of them:

- BSD systems have:

  ```
   #include <malloc/malloc.h>

   size_t malloc_size(const void *ptr);
  ```

  The `malloc_size()` function returns the size of the memory block that backs the allocation pointed to by `ptr`. The memory block size is always at least as large as the allocation it backs, and may be larger.

  ```
  size_t malloc_good_size(size_t size);
  ```

  The `malloc_good_size()` function rounds `size` up to a value that the allocator implementation can allocate without adding any padding; it then returns that rounded-up value.
- The GNU libC has:

  ```
   #include <malloc.h>

   size_t malloc_usable_size (void *ptr);
  ```

  The  `malloc_usable_size()` function returns the number of usable bytes in the block pointed to by `ptr`, a pointer to a block of memory allocated by **malloc(3)** or a related function.

  `malloc_usable_size()` returns the number of usable bytes in the block of allocated memory pointed to by `ptr`.  If `ptr` is `NULL`, `0`  is returned.